# how do i update or delete nested dictionary in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I would like to delete or update values in nested dictionary

Eg.

```
d:`date`tab`col!((2022.12.01;2022.12.03);`TRADE`SYM;`ID`CODE`PIN`NAME)
```

I would like to update `` `PIN `` to `` `Yen `` or maybe delete `` `PIN `` and `` `CODE `` from the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be slightly fiddly due to the nested nature but replacing values could be done with a dictionary and fills. This would replace all instances of `PIN` if there were multiple.

```
@[d;`col;{x^(enlist[`PIN]!enlist`YEN) x}]
date| 2022.12.01 2022.12.03
tab | `TRADE`SYM
col | `ID`CODE`YEN`NAME
```

Deletions could be done with `except`.

```
q)@[d;`col;except[;`PIN`CODE]]
date| 2022.12.01 2022.12.03
tab | TRADE      SYM
col | ID         NAME
```

I wouldn't be surprised to find better ways to do both these actions.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
q)@[d;`col;{x where not x in`CODE`PIN}]
date| 2022.12.01 2022.12.03
tab | TRADE      SYM
col | ID         NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Very minor mods to @Thomas Smyth-Treliant:

```
@[d;`col;] {x^(.[!]1#'`PIN`Yen) x}   / (1)
@[d;`col;] except[;`PIN`Yen]         / (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use amend in an implicit function to update nested values in a dictionary:

```
{.[d;(`col;x);:;`your`update]} where d[`col] in `ID`PIN
```

Output:

```
date| 2022.12.01 2022.12.03
tab | `TRADE`SYM
col | `your`CODE`update`NAME
```